# How can i use both of them correctly ("there + a place" in a sentence)

Tags: usage

I know that " **There** Refers to a Place ". However, i'm a little bit confused. I know it's wrong but I'm trying to use both words "there" and "a specific place" in a sentence and the examples below make sense to me. Could someone clear up this situation for me?

Each team has to be maximum 11 players = There cannot be more than 11 player of a team.

A-There cannot be more than 11 players of a team.

B-There cannot be more than 11 players in a team.

Just a native speaker say to me that it's impossible. Because i can't stop myself from thinking about it. :)

Comment: There are many ways of using "there" that don't refer to an actual "place".

Comment: That's why it makes sense to me. I just believed that explanation of there and then i was confused. ("there refers to a place")

Comment: No, not to a place here. This is the existential pronoun "there", not the locative preposition "there". Compare "There (existential) are 11 players over there (locative)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example sentence, "there" is used as a [pronoun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/there). It does not really refer to a place in this context. Here the word is used to introduce an [existential clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_clause).

Native speakers will usually say "players **on** a team", so your sentence should be:

> There cannot be more than 11 players on a team.

Again, "there" doesn't refer to a *place* where the teams will be; it is just a pronoun introducing the situation described by the sentence.

Comment: This is existential "there".